# ¿Cómo heredo un datalist en in input?

Tags: javascript, php, dom

Tengo un formulario de altas, el cual quiero agregar más filas para agregar multiples altas, pero al momento de clonar mis campos de texto, no se crean los nuevos.

```
<center><input type="button" class="form-control" onClick="addRow('tablaArticulos')" value="Agregar otro artículo" style="height: 40px; font-size:20px" /> <INPUT type="button" value="Borrar fila(s)" class="form-control" style="height: 40px; font-size:20px" onClick="deleteRow('tablaArticulos')" /><br/><br/></center>
    <table id="tablaArticulos" border="0" summary="Agregar" align=center width=950px cellpadding=5px>
        <tr style="background-color: #F2F2F2;font-style: bold;">
            <td><center><em>Selección</em></center></td>
            <td><center><em>Nombre</em></center></td>
            <td><center><em>Nombre del proveedor</em></center></td>
            <td><center><em>Descripci&oacuten</em></center></td>
            <td><center><em>Num. de parte</em></center></td>
            <td><center><em>Cantidad</em></center></td>
            <td><center><em>Categoria</em></center></td>
            <td><center><em>Ubicaci&oacuten</em></center></td>
            <td><center><em>Responsable</em></center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <TD><center><em><INPUT onclick="toggle(this)" type="checkboox" name="chkbox[]" title="Seleccionar todos"/></TD></em></center></TD>
            <td><center><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre[1]" name="nombre[1]" size="25" maxlength="150" required/></center></td>
            <td  style="text-align: center;">
               <?php
                  echo'<input type="text" name="marca[1]" class="form-control" list="empresas_todas">';
                  echo "<datalist id='empresas_todas'>";
                  include ('conexion.php');
                  $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM proveedores order by nombre_proveedor asc"); //consulta de la tabla                 
                  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
                     echo "<option value='".$row['nombre_proveedor']."'>".$row['nombre_proveedor']."</option>";
                  }
                    echo "</datalist></input>";                  
               ?>
           </td>
           <td><center><input class="form-control" id="descripcion[1]" type="text" name="descripcion[1]" size="25" maxlength="570" required/></center></td>
           <td><center><input type="text" class="form-control" id="no_parte[1]" name="no_parte[1]" size="20" maxlength="170" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" /></center></td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="cantidad[1]" NAME="cantidad[1]" class="form-control" type="number" pattern="\d*"/ min="1" value="1">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <SELECT id="categoria[1]" name="categoria[1]" class="form-control" style="width: 117px">
                            <?php
                                include ('conexion.php');
                                $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM categorias order by categoria asc"); //consulta de la tabla                  
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
                                    echo "<option value='".$row['categoria']."'>".$row['categoria']."</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </SELECT>
                    </td>
                    <td><center><input class="form-control" type="text" id="ubicacion[1]" name="ubicacion[1]" size="25" maxlength="150" required/></center></td></td>
                    <td><center><SELECT class="form-control" id="responsable[1]" NAME="responsable[1]" style="width: 117px">
                        <? 
                            include ('conexion.php');
                            $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM responsables order by nombre asc"); //consulta de la tabla                    
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
                                echo "<option value='".$row['nombre']."'>".$row['nombre']."</option>";
                            }
                        ?> 
                    </SELECT></center></td>
                </tr>
            </table><br/>
            <center> <input type="submit" class="form-control" style="height: 40px; font-size:20px" value="Guardar"/> </center>

<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.name="chkbox[]";
            cell1.style="text-align: center";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var element2 = document.getElementById("nombre[1]").cloneNode(true);
            element2.class="form-control";
            element2.type = "text";
            element2.name = "nombre["+rowCount+"]";
            element2.style="form-control";
            cell2.style="text-align: center";
            cell2.appendChild(element2);

            var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
            var element3 = document.createElement("INPUT");
            element3.list="empresas_todas";
            document.body.appendChild(element3);
            cell3.appendChild(element3);
            var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
            var element4=document.getElementById("descripcion[1]").cloneNode(true);
            element4.type="text";
            element4.name="descripcion["+rowCount+"]";
            cell4.appendChild(element4);

            var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
            var element5=document.getElementById("no_parte[1]").cloneNode(true);
            element5.type="text";
            element5.name="no_parte["+rowCount+"]";
            cell5.appendChild(element5);

            var cell6=row.insertCell(5);
            var element6 = document.getElementById("cantidad[1]").cloneNode(true);
            element6.type="SELECT";
            element6.name="cantidad["+rowCount+"]";
            cell6.style="text-align: center";
            cell6.appendChild(element6);

            var cell7=row.insertCell(6);
            var element7=document.getElementById("categoria[1]").cloneNode(true);
            element7.type="SELECT";
            element7.name="cantidad["+rowCount+"]";
            cell7.appendChild(element7);

            var cell8=row.insertCell(7);
            var element8=document.getElementById("ubicacion[1]").cloneNode(true);
            element8.type="text";
            element8.name="ubicacion["+rowCount+"]";
            cell8.appendChild(element8);

            var cell9=row.insertCell(8);
            var element9=document.getElementById("responsable[1]").cloneNode(true);
            element9.type="SELECT";
            element9.name="responsable["+rowCount+"]";
            cell9.appendChild(element9);

        }
</SCRIPT>
```

Se me ocurrió crear los elementos de nuevo pero tampoco se mostraban en la nueva fila :s

Gracias!

Comment: No consigo reproducir el problema. [Copié tu código a JSFiddle y funciona sin problemas](https://jsfiddle.net/hza2qbo6/1/). ¿Qué es lo que te da error?

Comment: Agregar listas dentro de un input, quiero heredar las propiedades de estilo y lista en las nuevas filas

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código html generado en lugar del PHP? Y si el problema es que los estilos no se aplican bien, quizás deberías incluir los estilos para que se vea el error. Lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en el centro de ayuda.

Comment: Necesito php para ciertas validaciones y conexiones, pero en script lo unico que hago es clonar un elemento por su id, trayendome todos sus valores. Lo que no sé es por qué si también lo creo con var variable=document.createElement("INPUT"); y utilizo variable.list="mi_lista"; no se muestra la propiedad list en la etiqueta input...

Comment: Gracias por añadir esa explicación final, ahora veo el problema. Y es fácil de solucionar, te escribo una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás asignando el atributo `list` con la notación de punto (`t3.list`) y debes hacerlo con `setAttribute()`:

```
t3.setAttribute("list", "empresas_todas");
```

Una vez solucionado eso, el dropdown ya se rellana correctamente (puedes verlo en este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hza2qbo6/2/)).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, creo que intenté utilizar el setAttribute pero como estoy en Sublime y no me muestrala sugerencia, no lo estuve utilizando.